# Como consultar se um registro existe em cakephp 2.6?

Tags: cakephp-2

Gostaria de saber se um registro existe em cakephp 2.6
Como todo mundo sabe, o cakephp tem que usar a chave id, porém
essa tabela é uma chave composta por 4 campos.

Dei uma lida e tentei usar beforeSave(), checkUnique e não consegui fazer funcionar.

- Sou iniciante, qualquer instrução é bem vinda.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu precisava checar se existia um registro aonde a chave são 4 campos.

Consegui resolver. Segue o que eu fiz.

---

Deixei isso no fim do meu model

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    $any = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'Recibo.funcionario_id' => $this->data['Recibo']['funcionario_id'],
        'Recibo.loja_id' => $this->data['Recibo']['loja_id'],
        'Recibo.ano' => $this->data['Recibo']['ano'],
        'Recibo.mes' => $this->data['Recibo']['mes'])));
    if($any)
    {
        return false;
    }else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

e deixei uma mensagem no controller para avisar que não incluiu.

```
if ($this->Recibo->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $recibo_id=$this->Recibo->getInsertId();
                    foreach($this->request->data['ItenRecibo'] as $person) 
                    {
                    //loop for each person added
                        $person['recibo_id']=$recibo_id;
                        $this->Recibo->ItenRecibo->create();
                        $this->Recibo->ItenRecibo->save($person);
                    }//end foreach
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Recibo salvo no BD'); 
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));                
            }else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Recibo já cadastrado para esse funcionário nesta data!');
            }
```